# Editor de texto simples em C

Tags: c, array, string, matriz, editor-de-texto

Tenho o seguinte exercício proposto:

> Faça um programa que imite um editor de textos. Inicialmente você irá ler os dados digitados pelo usuário (linhas de texto) e criar um vetor em memória onde serão armazenados os textos fornecidos pelo usuário (texto de 1 até no máximo 50 linhas). O usuário vai escrever o seu texto, terminando por uma linha onde ele irá escrever apenas a palavra ‘FIM’, o que determina que ele não deseja mais digitar linhas de texto. Sendo assim, o texto final pode ter um número variável de linhas, entre 1 e 50. Salvar o conteúdo armazenado na memória neste vetor, em um arquivo texto em disco.

Porém eu não estou acertando na lógica do vetor de string, sem contar que o texto digitado não é inserido no arquivo .txt

Segue abaixo meu código até o momento.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese");         // acentuação adequada
    FILE *arq;                              // cria variável ponteiro para referenciar na
                                            // memoria um tipo de arquivo txt, no caso o
                                            // user.txt
    char linha[50];
    int i;

    arq = fopen("editor.txt", "w");         // abrindo o arquivo

    if (arq == NULL)                      // testando se o arquivo foi realmente criado
    {
        printf("Erro na abertura do arquivo!");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Digite um texto de no máximo 50 linhas.\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)            //contador de linhas
    {
        fgets(linha, i, arq);           //armazenando no arquivo .txt as linhas digitadas
        if (strcmp(linha,'FIM')==0)     //se digitado "FIM" terminar o texto
        {
            i = 50;
            printf("Você terminou o seu texto.");
        }
    }
    fclose(arq);                            // fechando o arquivo
}
```

Desde já, agradeço.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você estava no caminho certo, mas errou algumas coisas:

1. `char linha[50];` não significa um texto de 50 linhas, e sim uma só linha com 50 caracteres. Acho que o que você queria era algo como `char texto[MAX_LINHAS][COMPRIMENTO];`, onde `MAX_LINHAS` é 50 e `COMPRIMENTO` é o tamanho máximo de cada linha.
2. `fgets` serve para ler, só que você quer ler o que o usuário digitar, e não ler o conteúdo do arquivo. O segundo parâmetro é o tamanho máximo do texto a ser digitado, e não o número da linha. Assim sendo, você deveria usar `fgets(texto[i], COMPRIMENTO, stdin);`
3. Para strings, use aspas duplas. Assim sendo, deveria ser `"FIM"` ao invés de `'FIM'`. É importante entender a diferença das aspas simples (para caracteres que podem ser representados numericamente) das aspas duplas (para strings).
4. Após ler o texto do usuário, salve-o no arquivo. Para fazer isso, você pode usar o `fprintf`.
5. O `fgets` inclui o "`\n`" no final do texto que o usuário digita (caso não seja grande demais). Assim sendo, é necessário removê-lo.

Acho que o seu código deve ficar assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>

#define MAX_LINHAS 50
#define COMPRIMENTO 200

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese");
    char linha[MAX_LINHAS][COMPRIMENTO];

    int linhas_lidas;

    printf("Digite um texto de no máximo %d linhas.\n", MAX_LINHAS);
    for (linhas_lidas = 0; linhas_lidas < MAX_LINHAS; linhas_lidas++) {
        fgets(texto[linhas_lidas], COMPRIMENTO, stdin);

        // Remove o \n do final, se houver.
        int t = strlen(texto[linhas_lidas]);
        if (texto[linhas_lidas][t - 1] == '\n') {
            texto[linhas_lidas][t - 1] = 0;
        }

        if (strcmp(texto[linhas_lidas], "FIM") == 0) {
            printf("Você terminou o seu texto.");
            break;
        }
    }

    FILE *arq = fopen("editor.txt", "w");

    if (arq == NULL) {
        printf("Erro na abertura do arquivo!");
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < linhas_lidas; i++) {
        fprintf(arq, "%s\n", texto[i]);
    }
    fclose(arq);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! a única coisa que ainda não está funcionando é a comparação com o "FIM", eu vou dar mais uma pesquisada sobre como isso funciona. mas você me ajudou muito, principalmente a entender melhor os conceitos dessas funções de manipulação de arquivos.

Comment: @BrunoMarques Resposta editada. Acho que agora deve estar redondinho.

Comment: Muito Obrigado!

Answer (score -1):

A comparação com a string "FIM" não está funcionando porque você deve tratar o "enter" (\n) armazenado com o texto (a função fgets() captura o "enter" como parte da string), seria como comparar "FIM\n" com "FIM". Pra isso, existe o seguinte algoritmo:

```
fgets (string, TAM_STRING - 1, stdin);
tam = strlen (string);
string[tam - 1] = '\0';
```

A variável "tam" pode ser int, short unsigned ou short.

O que ele faz é deslocar o terminador de string '\0' para o índice onde estaria o "enter" (\n).

Ou você pode simplesmente comparar com FIM\n, mesmo, que deve funcionar.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).